# Why is my query only Updating one field

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Rows in the query can be one or many (up to a 100 rows), the update query is working fine if the query output has only one row of data, but when the output has many rows of data, only the very last of the selected rows will be updated, what am I missing?

Some background: Employee needs to be moved from one location to another, the insert query writes the data in the database, but leaving the RECEIPT date blank. Many employees can be released from one location to another... This happens on a different form and is working perfectly.

Now the recipient must accept these employees, the update query runs in the background after a submit form and all it does, is enter today's date ($d) in the $move_receipt_date field. But as I mentioned earlier, only the very last row is effected in my update query...

Here is the select query that gets the data and the update query, pretty straight forward:

```
    <?php
    include("../../xxx.xxx");
        $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname)
            or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
        $query = "SELECT `move_id`,`empl_no`,`empl_jc_code` AS old_jc_code,`new_jc_code`,`move_date`,`move_receipt_date`,`move_reason`
            FROM `empl_movement` 
            WHERE `new_jc_code` = '$empl_jc_code' AND `move_receipt_date` = 0";
        $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
            or die ("Couldn't execute query. "
                .mysqli_error($cxn));

                echo "<table><br>
        <tr>
         <th>Move ID</th>
         <th>Employee No</th>
         <th>Old JC Code</th>
         <th>New JC Code</th>
         <th>Release Date</th>
         <th>Receipt Date</th>
         <th>Reason for Move</th>
        </tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            extract($row);
            echo "<tr>\n
                <td>$move_id</td>\n
                <td>$empl_idno</td>\n
                <td>$old_jc_code</td>\n
                <td>$new_jc_code</td>\n
                <td>$move_date</td>\n
                <td>$move_receipt_date</td>\n  //this is the field that will be updated
                <td>$move_reason</td>\n
                </tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table><br>";        ?>

    <?php
    include("../../xxx.xxx");
        $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname)
            or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
        $query = "UPDATE `empl_movement` SET `move_receipt_date` = '$d' 
                    WHERE `move_id` = '$move_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
            or die ("Couldn't execute query. "
                .mysqli_error($cxn));
    ?>
```

Comment: There's a `WHERE` clause on that `UPDATE` query, which looks like it's filtering on an identifier.  If there's only one matching record then it's only going to update one record.  How many records have the same `move_id`?

Comment: I understand that my qyery is only selecting the last of the move_id, but my select query can pop out anything from 1 to 100 lines, each with a different (unique) move_id.

Comment: I know what my problem is here, but I don't know how to fix it, this is the first time I've had to make multiple updates in a query using a select query

Comment: What does the `SELECT` query have to do with the `UPDATE` query?  According to the code you posted, that `UPDATE` query is only executed once.  (And the code isn't showing where any of these query values come from.)  Or did you mean to do that in whatever the `extract` function is?  Because that's not clear at all in the code shown.  If so, why perform the update in a loop instead of just updating based on the same `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` query?

Comment: The select query gets all the relevant data where the move_receipt_date is emplty, but there may be more than one empl_jc_code and (eg) JOHN should only be able to receipt employees from his jc code, this creates a "paper trail" if SARA for instance have not receipt employees onto her location / jc code

Comment: I understand that the `SELECT` query *gets* data.  That is, in fact, what a `SELECT` query does.  But look at your code... How is that in any way related to the `UPDATE` query?  If that `UPDATE` query is running *once* then it's only going to update the record(s) identified by its `WHERE` clause *once*.  This has nothing to do with the business process you're trying to model.

Comment: I have updated the code, should I nest the select query within the update query?

Comment: Nest it how?  If you want to update the same records that are in the `SELECT` query then use the same `WHERE` conditions.  The condition in your `UPDATE` query is *very different* from the condition in your `SELECT` query, so I really don't know why you expect them to behave identically.  Different things are different.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your Query you update only one field i.e. empl_movement.